# What are the "sideways triangle patterns" called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

So I've seen this pattern in the background and banners of websites, but I don't know what it's called. I want to see more examples, and learn how to do it myself (Using CS2).

This website has a example of what I'm talking about in it's seemless background: http://projectmgame.com/en/

Comment: could you attach a [screenshot](http://superuser.com/questions/229551/is-there-a-snipping-tool-for-windows-xp/229556#229556), because the site will eventually change. it is good practice on Stackexchange to copy the part of the site you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a tessellation since the triangles used are regular and repeating in a unified way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a **pattern** which is the same thing as a tessellation, just not such a "fancy" word.

Just because it happens to be a pattern/tessellation of triangles, that does not give it a specific name.